# Can't multiple append() within a for loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the following code to append 40 new div elements to a #colors div:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $node = $("<div></div>");
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        $divg.append($node);
    }
});
```

At the end I get the following:

```
<div id="colors">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Could someone please tell me what's happening?

I can't figure out.

Comment: There can only be one `id` attribute in a HTML document page. Use `.colors` and see if that works.

Comment: You are just appending same element over and over again, making it just move (to the same place). You should append each time a clone instead `$divg.append($node.clone());`. That's said, regarding performance, your code isn't optimized for sure

Comment: A. Wolff, what would you recommend performance wise?

Comment: Duplicate of [jQuery .appendTo or more general for loop not working as expected](/q/5529091/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

When you do `var $node = $("<div></div>");` you're creating a jQuery object with a newly-created `div` inside it which isn't in the DOM yet. The first time you append it, you put it in the DOM. The second time you append it, you *move* it. (Well, you would if you were appending it to something else, but actually you're just putting it in the same place.)

If you want *multiple* divs, you need to create more than one. [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) does that, but in that code, you could just do it directly.

Append is perfectly happy with markup:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        $divg.append("<div></div>");
    }
});
```

Or if it's important to create the element first because you're doing things with it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $node;
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        $node = $("<div></div>");
        $divg.append($node);
    }
});
```

Or using `clone`, but in this case I probably wouldn't:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $node = $("<div></div>");
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        $divg.append($node.clone());
    }
});
```

(Note that technically, that creates an extra `div`, but it's fine, that isn't expensive and it doesn't get added to the DOM anywhere.)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain it better that T.J's explanation. Use the `clone()` function to create a new `div`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    var $node = $("<div></div>");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        $divg.append($node.clone());
    }
});
```

```css
#colors div{
  border : 1px solid red;
  width : 50px;
  height : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colors">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used plain JavaScript (I wrapped it in a `$(function(){})`, because I was going to write jQuery initially.)because (at least for me) it's easier to read the code (plus I suck at jQuery too many options makes my mind lazy.)

Although cloning is the common way to accomplish your goal, there are other ways to iterate through the creation of elements such as `createElement()` and `appendChild();`

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    var shade = document.getElementById('colors');
    var x = document.createElement('div');
    x.classList.add('x');
    shade.appendChild(x);
  }
});
```

```css
#colors {
  border: 3px inset black;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: table;
}
.x {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="colors">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

move var $ node = .. .into the loop:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $divg = $('#colors');
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        var $node = $("<div></div>");
        $divg.append($node);
    }
});
```

or even:

```
 $divg.append("<div></div>");
```