# Two dropdown values from an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, select

Simple question: I want to loop the array values in two dropdown lists in HTML using JavaScript. But only one dropdown is working. If I comment the one, the another one works. I want to fill the values in both the dropdown lists. What's wrong in this simple code?

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    select2.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705364/cant-multiple-append-within-a-for-loop#answer-34705416

Comment: You cannot append the same element to two different parents. You'll need to create a second element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do not use the same element for both controls. Clone it first

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
  select2.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber">
  <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2">
  <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its worked bro but y clonenode y cant it accept directly

Comment: @SanthoshPrabu For the same reason you can't be in two places at once, a DOM node can't have two parents

Answer (score 9):

Create a option element for each select,appendChild doesn't clone the element so the second append takes the element from the first

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
   var el1 = document.createElement("option");
  el1.textContent = opt;
  el1.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el1);
  select2.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber">
  <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2">
  <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2"); 
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    var el2 = document.createElement("option");
    el2.textContent = opt;
    el2.value = opt;
    select2.appendChild(el2);    
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Create two different nodes and add them.

Reason to why your code didn't work is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30667148/6285410)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Mr.7 ya working bro. Thanks see VadimB answer its simple

Comment: Yeah! It is. @SanthoshPrabu

Answer (score 4):

You can use both JavaScript and jQuery:

```js
  var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

    $.each(options, function(key, value) {
        $('#selectNumber,#selectNumber2').append($("<option/>", {
            value: key,
            text: value
        }));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNumber">
 <option>Choose a number1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2">
 <option>Choose a number2</option>
</select>
```

This is JavaScript code:

```
<script>
        var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
        var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
        var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
            select2.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is other option if you want separate the option code

```
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
    var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];

        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);

        var e2 = document.createElement("option");
        e2.textContent = opt;
        e2.value = opt;
        select2.appendChild(e2);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method without clone ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njv661on/)):

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    select.add(new Option(opt,opt));
    select2.add(new Option(opt,opt));
}
```

Read more about the `add` function for JavaScript select [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the element you are creating can only be append in one parent. Not both. Bellow the code snippet that works

```
var select2 = document.getElementById("selectNumber2");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
  var copy = el.cloneNode(true);
  select2.appendChild(copy);
}
```

Just notice the line `var copy = el.cloneNode(true);` this create a new clone of the element, and then append it to another `select`.